# Clementine current song as empathy status

Tags: empathy, clementine

Any plugin available to set Clementine's current playing song as empathy status

[update]

I've tried it and was not succesful, here is my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671763/error-setting-status-to-empathy-with-dbus/7760194#7760194

but I've figured out that it is not possible to set status of empathy through dbus

http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/spec/Connection_Interface_Simple_Presence.html#Method:SetPresence

regards

[update]
answer found on stack overflow link given above
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671763/error-setting-status-to-empathy-with-dbus/8160857#8160857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been suggested that this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8160857/) answers the subject:

```
import dbus
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
player = session_bus.get_object('org.mpris.clementine', '/Player')
iface = dbus.Interface(player, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer')
metadata = iface.GetMetadata()
status = "♫ ".decode('utf8')+metadata["title"]+' - '+metadata["album"]+" ♫".decode('utf8')
print status
from gi.repository import TelepathyGLib as Tp
from gi.repository import GObject
loop = GObject.MainLoop()
am = Tp.AccountManager.dup()
am.prepare_async(None, lambda *args: loop.quit(), None)
loop.run()
am.set_all_requested_presences(Tp.ConnectionPresenceType.AVAILABLE,
'available', status)
```

Comment: I know I shd have updated the question here too. I've posted the question over ther I can't accpet your answer bt thanx

Answer (score 0):

The script suggested in comments worked for me after a `aptitude install libtelepathy-glib-dev`.

Comment: I know I shd have updated the question here too. I've posted the question over ther I can't accpet your answer bt thanx